# Flutter array of images

Tags: flutter

I have `array` of images in

```
var images=[];
```

Now I want the each images from `array` to be passed in

```
circleavatar(child:Image.Asset(here),),
```

So that I can displayed each images in `circle shape`.

Help me please !

Comment: Does that image in listview or it just normal list ?

Comment: It's in array form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CircleAvatar(
            radius: 30.0,
            backgroundImage:
                Image.Asset(Images),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          )
```

Comment: No need loop directly pass images

Comment: Please add at least some explanation as though why this answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code related with your desire

```
ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: images
                    .map((imgUrl) => CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage(imgUrl),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
              ),
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not in list view

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that :

then you can show it where ever you're showing a list of widgets like columan or row or listview.

```
var imagesList =new ListVWidgetC();
for(int i=0;iVimagesClength;i++)
{
imagesListCadd( CircleAvatar ( ghackgroundImage: AssetImage(imgUrl));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will help you to add images in circle avatar widget

```
class UserAvatar extends StatelessWidget {
  UserAvatar({Key? key, required this.image}) : super(key: key);

  String image = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CircleAvatar(
      // TODO : set mulitple images in list
      backgroundImage: AssetImage(image),
      // backgroundImage: arrCarLogo[index],
    );
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
return ListTile(
  leading: UserAvatar(image: *array of your image*),
);
```